# how to create store with react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

Sorry for the silly question but i do not know how to combine together my existing redux store definition with applyMiddleware.

This is my current working code:

```
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    routing: routerReducer
  })
)
```

I would like to add this middleware somehow to my store definition:

```
applyMiddleware(...thunk)
```

My solution does not work, I get a "**TypeError: dbg is undefined**" in the web browser:

```
const store = createStore(
  applyMiddleware(...thunk),
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    routing: routerReducer
  })
)
```

Could you please give me a quick help? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    routing: routerReducer
  }), 
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
)
```

**Syntax:**

> createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])

`Enhancer` must be the last parameter for `createStore()`

Read more from [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html#createstorereducer-preloadedstate-enhancer)

Answer (score 4):

better solution:

app.js:

```
    import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
    import {browserHistory, Router, Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
    import {syncHistoryWithStore, routerMiddleware} from 'react-router-redux';
    import {reducers} from './reducers';

   const initial_state = {};

    let middleware = applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(browserHistory));
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
            middleware = compose(middleware, window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension());
        }
        const store   = createStore(reducers, initial_state, middleware);
        const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
```

reducers:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {routerReducer} from 'react-router-redux';
import users from './users';

export const reducers = combineReducers({
    routing:routerReducer,
    users: users
});
```